# Spring Boot Service is null

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, null

I'm currently working with Spring Boot, creating a CommandLineRunner. Everything worked fine until I tried to @Autowired my classes: They are always null and got the same error from Spring:  "Error creating bean with name 'initBatch': Injection of autowired dependencies failed: 
No qualifying bean of type [Utils] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations. I still can't figure out why this error happens. 
This is my code:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class InitBatch implements CommandLineRunner {

@Autowired
private Utils Utils;

@Override
public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Hello World");          
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    SpringApplication.run(InitBatch.class, args);
}


@Bean
public ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource() {
    ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();

       messageSource.setBasename("instances");
    return messageSource;
}
```

This is the Utils class that is causing problem:

```
@Configurable
@Service
public class Utils { 

private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Utils.class);

     //NUMEROUS METHODS...
 }
```

Also, I have another Init that loads de app as an WS . Running everything on a sever, the same classes work great. This is the other Init that is working:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan({ "ws.controller","ws.service",
"ws.dao", "ws.util", "ws.filtro",
"ws.repository", "ws.model.log", "ws.logger.impl"})
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Init extends SpringBootServletInitializer { 

private static final int SECS = 10;

@Override
protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
    return application.sources(Init.class);
}

/**
 * Main method.
 *
 * @param args String[].
 * @throws Exception Exception.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    SpringApplication.run(Init.class, args);
}


@Bean
public ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource() {
    ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();

    messageSource.setBasename("instances");
    messageSource.setCacheSeconds(SECS);
    return messageSource;
}
}
```

I just don't understand why using the same files, with the same configuration, works with Init.java (as a tomcat web app), but all the same files are null with the CommandLineRunner.

Any suggestions ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Need to specify `ComponentScan` annotation with package at `InitBatch`(as `Utils` class in different package) for scanning beans at runtime.

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("ws.util")
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class InitBatch implements CommandLineRunner {
...
}
```

`@SpringBootApplication` documentation -

> Many Spring Boot developers always have their main class annotated
>   with @Configuration, @EnableAutoConfiguration and @ComponentScan.
>   Since these annotations are so frequently used together (especially if
>   you follow the best practices above), Spring Boot provides a
>   convenient @SpringBootApplication alternative.

Comment: You are right, I messed up my previous test with this configuration.  If I put the @ComponentScan works like a charm. Thanks!